# Pandas - Table Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have this table

[image]

and want to get this output:
[image]

The expected logic is i want to strip any columns that have periods in the column name, after the third period. In this case, there are 4, and after stripping the column names we will have 2 unique column names. (Cars and Food)

The additional column "trait" is just the value before the third period. and will be in the expected output.

The expected output will have more rows as it is pivoted. Also assume this case for x column names that should have periods in them.

I am not able to get it yet, but my current code is pasted below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'GenoType': [1, 2, 4],
    'Parameter1': [2, 2, 787],
    'First.Second.Third.Car': ['Honda', 'Tesla', 'Jeep'],
    'First.Second.Third.Food': ['Pizza', 'Fries', 'Grapes'],
    'Red.Orange.Yellow.Car': ['Acura', 'BMW', 'Toyota'],
    'Red.Orange.Yellow.Food': ['Burger', 'Potatoes', 'Wings']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars=['GenoType', 'Parameter1'], var_name='Trait', value_name='Value')
melted_df[['Trait', 'Column']] = melted_df['Trait'].str.rsplit('.', n=1, expand=True)

pivoted_df = melted_df.pivot_table(index=['GenoType', 'Parameter1', 'Trait'], columns='Column', values='Value', aggfunc='first')
pivoted_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pivoted_df.columns.name = ''

# Melt the pivoted_df to obtain the final output
final_df = pivoted_df.melt(id_vars=['GenoType', 'Parameter1', 'Trait'], var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
final_df.sort_values(by=['GenoType', 'Parameter1', 'Trait', 'Column'], inplace=True)
final_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

expanded_df = final_df.pivot_table(index=['GenoType', 'Parameter1', 'Trait'], columns='Column', values='Value', aggfunc='first')
expanded_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
expanded_df.columns.name = ''
expanded_df = expanded_df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(expanded_df)
```

Comment: In terms of extra a.b.c.d columns, will *all* the columns always include all of the result column names (in this case `Car` and `Food`)? So if you added `A.B.C.Animal`, would that mean you would also have `A.B.C.Car`, `A.B.C.Food`,`First.Second.Animal` and `Red.Orange.Yellow.Animal` i.e. every trait with every feature?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#create MulitIndex by first 2 columns
df1 = df.set_index(['GenoType', 'Parameter1'])

#filter Food columns
cols = df1.filter(regex=r'\.Food').columns

#join with rename Food columns names
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(cols, cols[::-1])))])

#create MulitIndex in columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.rsplit('.', n=1, expand=True)

#reshape
df1 = df1.stack(0).sort_index(level=2).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'Trait'})
print (df1)

    GenoType  Parameter1               Trait     Car      Food
0          1           2  First.Second.Third   Honda     Pizza
1          1           2  First.Second.Third   Honda    Burger
2          2           2  First.Second.Third   Tesla     Fries
3          2           2  First.Second.Third   Tesla  Potatoes
4          4         787  First.Second.Third    Jeep    Grapes
5          4         787  First.Second.Third    Jeep     Wings
6          1           2   Red.Orange.Yellow   Acura    Burger
7          1           2   Red.Orange.Yellow   Acura     Pizza
8          2           2   Red.Orange.Yellow     BMW  Potatoes
9          2           2   Red.Orange.Yellow     BMW     Fries
10         4         787   Red.Orange.Yellow  Toyota     Wings
11         4         787   Red.Orange.Yellow  Toyota    Grapes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this using an iterative [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). This will work for an arbitrary number of columns:

```py
data = {
    'GenoType': [1, 2, 4],
    'Parameter1': [2, 2, 787],
    'First.Second.Third.Car': ['Honda', 'Tesla', 'Jeep'],
    'First.Second.Third.Food': ['Pizza', 'Fries', 'Grapes'],
    'Red.Orange.Yellow.Car': ['Acura', 'BMW', 'Toyota'],
    'Red.Orange.Yellow.Food': ['Burger', 'Potatoes', 'Wings']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

traits = df.columns.str.extract(r'^((?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*)').dropna().drop_duplicates()[0].tolist()
features = df.columns.str.extract(r'^(?:[^.]*\.){3}(.*)$').dropna().drop_duplicates()[0].tolist()

out = df.melt(value_vars=[f'{t}.{features[0]}' for t in traits], value_name=features[0], id_vars=['GenoType', 'Parameter1'], var_name='Trait')
out['Trait'] = out['Trait'].str.extract(r'^((?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*)')
for f in features[1:]:
    dff = df.melt(value_vars=[f'{t}.{f}' for t in traits], value_name=f, id_vars=['GenoType', 'Parameter1'], var_name='Trait')
    out = out.merge(dff, on=['GenoType', 'Parameter1'], suffixes=['', '_y'])
    out.drop('Trait_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
out = out.sort_values('Trait', kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    GenoType  Parameter1               Trait     Car      Food
0          1           2  First.Second.Third   Honda     Pizza
1          1           2  First.Second.Third   Honda    Burger
2          2           2  First.Second.Third   Tesla     Fries
3          2           2  First.Second.Third   Tesla  Potatoes
4          4         787  First.Second.Third    Jeep    Grapes
5          4         787  First.Second.Third    Jeep     Wings
6          1           2   Red.Orange.Yellow   Acura     Pizza
7          1           2   Red.Orange.Yellow   Acura    Burger
8          2           2   Red.Orange.Yellow     BMW     Fries
9          2           2   Red.Orange.Yellow     BMW  Potatoes
10         4         787   Red.Orange.Yellow  Toyota    Grapes
11         4         787   Red.Orange.Yellow  Toyota     Wings
```